# About vectorial subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to find a and b to verify that $dimU=2$ where $U=<(1,1,0,a),(3,-1,b,-1),(-3,5,0,a)>$ that is a subspace of $ℝ^4$. I think $a=-1$ and $b=0$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How do you get to $a = -1$ and $b=0$?

Comment: @JohnMa $(1,1,0,a)=(3,−1,b,−1)$ ?

Comment: What about that first two term? They do not match...

Comment: @JohnMa I need to scalonate the three rows, and get values for $a$ and $b$ by Gauss?

Answer (score 1):

So as  $dim(U)=2$, then the above given three vectors  $u,v,w$ should be linearly dependent, and so according to the definition: there exists  $\alpha$, $\beta$, and  $\gamma $ real, not all zeros, such that $$ \alpha u +\beta v +\gamma w=0 $$ 
Accordingly, we have
$$ \alpha  +3\beta -3\gamma =0 $$ 
$$ \alpha  - \beta +5\gamma =0 $$ 
$$ b\beta =0 $$ 
$$ a\alpha -\beta  +a\gamma =0 $$ 
Subtracting  the first two equations we get  $$ \beta -2\gamma=0 \Rightarrow  \beta=2\gamma$$
Note that, if  $\beta=0$, then $\gamma =0$, and so from the first equation $\alpha =0$, but $\alpha$, $\beta$, and  $\gamma $ are taken to be not all zero , so this case can be excluded, i.e. $\beta\neq 0$ . Hnece from the third equation **$b=0$**.

From the last equation we have $$ a\alpha -\beta  +a\gamma =0  \Rightarrow  a\alpha -2\gamma  +a\gamma =0  \Rightarrow  a( \alpha+ \gamma )=2\gamma$$ 
But from the second  equation $$ \alpha  - \beta +5\gamma =0 \Rightarrow   \alpha  - 2\gamma +5\gamma =0 \Rightarrow \alpha=-3\gamma $$ Substituting just above we get  $$a( \alpha+ \gamma )=2\gamma \Rightarrow a(-3\gamma+ \gamma )=2\gamma \Rightarrow  -2\gamma  a =2\gamma$$
Hence $a=-1$.